# want to create a bot in visual studio (httpwebrequest) Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

So i made a bot with a viewcounter in it that visits a specific url in textbox.
Now i made it with the webbrowser1.navigate function.

I've heared that i need to make an httpwebrequest function instead of using the webbrowser1 function.

Should i use this code instead of the webbrowser1.navigate :
Here's my code im using :

> Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(txtUrl.Text, "", Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5" & vbCrLf & "Accept-Language: en-us" & vbCrLf)
    lblCount.Text += 1
End Sub
```

End Class

> Blockquote

i would lik to have it as webrequest instead of browser so should i use this below?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.it/");
 WebProxy a=new WebProxy(); a.Address=new Uri("http://97.107.137.97:8080"); 
 request.Proxy = a; 
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

and would like to put the URL in a textfield ?
Does anyone know how i can do that??

Thnx in advanced :)

Comment: The bottom section of code is C#.

Comment: Oh ok, do you know how to make the httpwebrequest what i've been asking? I would love to get some help with it.